# How I could receive SQLite database layout?

Tags: sqlite

For backward compatibility purpose I would like to know a layout of my database, i.e. which tables are incorporated in my database, for each table which columns are included, etc.

The `sqlite_master` table contains only table information. Theoretically I have access to this metadata information through SQLite API such as `sqlite3_column_database_name`, `sqlite3_column_table_name`, `sqlite3_column_origin_name`.

Could I have a direct **SQL query** to receive this data or it is stored internally?

Comment: The sqlite_master table contains the description of what tables there are. It doesn't list what tables or columns you're actually using; SQLite doesn't comprehend that at all.

Comment: May be I explained unclearly: I don’t want to know “what tables or columns I am actually using”, I would like to receive “the description of what tables there are” and which **columns** are included in these tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not stricly speaking SQL, *but* it is accessible *as* SQL in all sqlite implementations I know of:

http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info

An example:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, text1 TEXT NOT NULL, text2 TEXT, boolean1 BOOLEAN NOT NULL);
sqlite> pragma table_info('foo');
cid         name        type        notnull     dflt_value  pk        
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           id          INTEGER     0                       1         
1           text1       TEXT        1                       0         
2           text2       TEXT        0                       0         
3           boolean1    BOOLEAN     1                       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is what I am looking for and this approach works!

Comment: Thanks, .mode column is exactly what I am searching for to make the select result easy to read

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to receive “the description of what tables there are”

I'm mot sure what you mean by that.

You can get the SQL statements necessary to re-create your schema with `.schema`.

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE a (n integer);
CREATE TABLE b (n integer);
```

Also, `.dump` will give you those same SQL statements, and it will add INSERT statments to reproduce the data.

If part of what you want is just a list of tables, then `.tables` will do that for you.

[Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) (scroll down to "Special commands . . .")

Comment: _.schema_ and _.tables_ is only shortcut for `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master;` and `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` accordingly (Of course real used statement is more sophisticated – check your [reference](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)